# Tools to test coding style (Perl, JavaScript ) before a commit is allowed into the main repo

Tags: javascript, code-analysis, code-review, perl, mercurial

Can any one recommend a tool that will allow me to define a set of coding style requirements, and prevent anything that violates this style from being committed into the main HG repository.

I know that I can use hooks to prevent something getting into the repo. But I am not aware of any tools that can perform this sort of style analysis.

Things like my `$newArrayRef = $result;` would be allowed but `$newArrayRef= $result;` would not. And defining if a project uses camel case or underscores for variable names.

It would be nice if it could also check for anti-patterns in the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For JavaScript there is [JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint) which is itself written in JavaScript. The answer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835218/lint-like-program-for-perl) details a couple of possibilities for perl.  In either case you can wrap the call in a process that returns 0 if all the rules are met and -1 otherwise then call it in a pre-commit hook.

See the [redbook entry](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) on hooks for more information and the [config](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc) section on hooks for more information.  You ***might*** wish to allow local commits, *(possibly with warnings)*, but block push & pull, (with `preoutgoing` &/or `prechangegroup`), until the issues are all resolved as this would allow the user to commit changes to the local repository, sort them out, then commit & push the final version.